# How to join multiple apks and build a universal apk with Google App Bundle?

Tags: android, build, bundle

I want to sideload an apk to my android tv, since I can't download as it isn't native..

I have downloaded in my Android phone, but it's an Android App Bundle, when I backup only the base, and try to install it gives error when launching app.
I navigate to /data/app and get the base.apk and 3 split_config_xxxx.apk files.. It's only possible to install the base.apk, the splits gives errors when try to install. So is there anyway to join the splits with the base and create a universal apk, so i could sideload to my android tv?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that the Android App Bundle is purely a "publishing format", this means that an Android App Bundle cannot be directly installed onto a device. However, you can generate an APK set archive from an Android App Bundle. Using the generated APK set archive, you can then install an APK directly to your device. This is possible via a tool called `bundletool`. For example, with version 0.9.0 of the `bundletool`, you can do something similar to the following:

1. `bundletool build-apks --bundle your.aab --output artifact.apks --mode=universal`
2. `bundletool install-apks --apks artifact.apks`

Official Android documentation for `bundletool` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool). Specifically, take a look at the `--mode=universal` flag. You may also want to take a look at a similar SO question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616544/generate-universal-apk-from-android-app-bundle). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use --mode=universal in place of --universal. For example, you can run something like this:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=myapp_bundle.abb --output=myapp.apks --mode=universal
```

At the end you have myapp.apks, this file is something like a zip file. You can extract the content into a folder, for example:

```
unzip out.apks -d apks
```

Now in the folder apks you have only one apk, in my case universal.apk, that you can install as usual on any device.